# getting error for docker COPY command for dcproj project

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I am adding `docker-compose` project (`dcproj`) in my solution and moved the files to `Compose` folder

[image]

When I am trying to add the `COPY` command in docker file,

```
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Compose/docker-compose.dcproj", "Compose/"]
```

the copy is failed and giving below error,

> Step 59/78 : COPY ["Compose/docker-compose.dcproj", "Compose/"]
> ERROR: Service 'myTest' failed to build : COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder608017550/Compose/docker-compose.dcproj: no such file or directory

For `csproj` project I am NOT getting any error. Is the above error only specific to `dcproj project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue this morning, turns out the generation of the docker compose support in Visual Studio adds the following to a .dockerignore file in same folder as the docker-compose.
[image]

```
**/.classpath
**/.dockerignore
**/.env
**/.git
**/.gitignore
**/.project
**/.settings
**/.toolstarget
**/.vs
**/.vscode
**/*.*proj.user
**/*.dbmdl
**/*.jfm
**/azds.yaml
**/bin
**/charts
**/docker-compose*
**/Dockerfile*
**/node_modules
**/npm-debug.log
**/obj
**/secrets.dev.yaml
**/values.dev.yaml
LICENSE
README.md
```

Removing the line

```
**/docker-compose*
```

Fixed the issue for me, I was too busy looking in the project docker ignore files to notice this root one!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Error log
COPY ["Compose/docker-compose.dcproj", "Compose/"] ERROR: Service 'myTest' failed to build : COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder608017550/Compose/docker-compose.dcproj: no such file or directory

your copy "source path" is incorrect, make sure your DIR tree should be like this
src/
-> Compose
-> dockerfile

try using this -->

COPY ./Compose/docker-compose.dcproj Compose/

Comment: Thanks, `it's not working`. As I told the same folder structure works well for asp.net projects `csproj`. The only problem I am seeing with `dcproj` projects

Comment: okey are you able to open this file on this path "/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder608017550/Compose/docker-compose.dcproj" like to test it. go to your terminal and type "cat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder608017550/Compose/docker-compose.dcproj" and let me know the error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

From your Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /src
```

Workdir creates a directory inside the image and uses this for the current directory for all future commands. It's similar to running `mkdir -p /src; cd /src` in your command prompt. Note that these paths are for inside the image and do not relate to the paths in your host or the build context.

```
COPY ["Compose/docker-compose.dcproj", "Compose/"]
```

This copies the file from the build context into the image. You only have access to the build context when running copy or add steps in the Dockerfile. That build context is the single argument passed to `docker build` and is typically a single `.` meaning the current directory. docker-compose defaults to using the directory with the compose file as your context, so if you move the compose file, you move your context.

Two options to fix this are to adjust your copy step, or adjust your build context path. For the copy step, you can use:

```
COPY ["docker-compose.dcproj", "Compose/"]
```

Or for changing the context in the docker-compose.yml, you need a "build: context" entry, taking care to correctly indent the lines:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ..
```

For more on the compose file syntax, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build

And for more on the build context, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#usage

Comment: Thanks, `it's not working`. As I told the same folder structure works well for asp.net projects `csproj`. The only problem I am seeing with `dcproj` projects

Comment: @user584018 you need to find out where the build context is, are you building this by hand on the CLI? If not, the UI may be changing that path.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check path in .dockerignore file